# List of chat Commands

Tags: the-division

When playing The Division I used the chat command `/g` to talk just to my group.  Then every other message automatically went to group chat.  What I could not figure out is how to return to global chat.

So is there a list of chat commands I can reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are just 4 commands, thats not many but you dont need more. Here they are:

- /w [PlayerName]  -> Private Chat with the given Player (Whisper)
- /p, /g or /group -> Chat in your current group
- /1               -> You are going back to global chat (public)
- /s               -> Proximinity Chat

There is also a command that lets you Report Players:

- /report [PlayerName] -> reports the given Player

These are all chat commands which are currently in the game.

Comment: You'll see the prompt text and color change as soon as you hit `Space` after the command. You don't have to hit `Enter` to know that it will work. For whispering, enter the player's name after a space: `/w PlayerName`, then `Space` followed by your message as with the other commands.

Comment: Not sure if you'd consider that chat command, but it uses chat interface: `/report PlayerName`